# Windows Phone 8 access to SQL remote Database

Tags: sql, database, windows, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to develop a WP8 app, and I have a free online sql server (not windows azure).
How can I Access the Database from the phone app?
I tried a local WPF sevice and it worked, but it won't help if I'd like to upload the app to the store.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

As far as i'm aware, you can't access the database directly, you need a proxy web service for this, i recommend you to look at OData, REST APIs and also to JSON or XML to transfer your data from the database to your app.

Comment: How will the web service work when I'll upload my app to the store?

Comment: The web service will connect to the database and your application to the web service, then from your application you will send calls to the web service, and the web service will respond with whatever data you requested.