# How to connect to a SQL Server database already hosted on server with windows phone 8

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services, windows-phone-7

As I'm not that skilled in Windows Phone 8 development I would like to discuss/ask what is the best way to connect my Windows Phone 8 to a SQL Server database, I don't want to use Azure as I have already have the database present on server using for website. Please can anyone give me complete tutorial for the same or help in achieving it? And after connection, I want to fire select queries only from wp8 app using text box inputs from user

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Phone 8 access to SQL remote Database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18579086/windows-phone-8-access-to-sql-remote-database)

Comment: there is no tutorial there i want tutorial can you help me for finding tutorial for `**"The web service will connect to the database and your application to the web service, then from your application you will send calls to the web service, and the web service will respond with whatever data you requested."**`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check here [Windows Phone 8 access to SQL remote Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18579086/windows-phone-8-access-to-sql-remote-database)

Microsoft does not allow direct connection to remote databases, so you need to have a service ont the server connected to the database, that serves the content with http requests (using xml or json to represent the data)

Comment: can you give tutorial for the same

Comment: If you own the server you can create your own service that accepts web requests and according to them serves the data from your database as xml or json. How you do it depends on the schema of your data and i can't find a tutorial for your exact case. What you should do is search how to create a web service that serves xml or json or however you want to serve your data to your wp8 application from your MS-SQL database and adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Azure free 30 day trial: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/          To create a REST service in azure: http://www.brianhprince.com/2012/06/29/hosting-a-webapi-service-on-windows-azure-web-sites/        To support CRUD operations in WebAPI http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-a-web-api-that-supports-crud-operations use the HTTPClient library in WP8 to retrieve data. You can obviously also host your REST service on your server if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is using Web Services. In web services you can use  ASP.NET Web API. Its a framework that makes it easy to build HTTP services that you can use on your windows phone, JSON or XML, you decide. In your windows phone you can use a GET, PUT, POST, and DELETE request and get the WebAPI response appropriately.

You can implement one by using these tutorials:

[Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)

[Another Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/659131/A-Beginners-Tutorial-for-Understanding-and-Impleme).

I prefer using LINQ to query data in Web API using linq
[Linq Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)

For sorting purposes you can use odata:

[Odata for ASP .NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api)

To consume the Web API :
[Web API with windows phone](http://dotnetspeaks.com/DisplayArticle.aspx?ID=236)

Answer (score 0):

you can also make a simple web page that takes data from your phone as query string and return data as response, this web page should work as a bridge between you and your database. and you won't have to open the page from your phone, you will just send an HTTP request and get the response , this might help you : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh221581.aspx