# Windows Phone 8 connect to local SQL Server 2008 database

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, sql-server-2008-r2

I am creating an app for Windows Phone 8 that needs to access a SQL Server on our local network.  I have searched online and there seems to be a few ways to do this, but I am not sure why each one would be better than the others.

Since my database is on the local network, I was not sure if that changed anything.

My only experience is with desktop programs, so I do not want to move in a direction without at least some advice.

Thanks!

UPDATE

I ended up creating a WCF service and using JSON.net in Visual Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fro here:http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/a653ad41-59f7-41b7-82e8-3b2c76d7dec6/sql-server-connection-for-windows-phone-8?forum=wpdevelop

You can't directly interact with a SQL Server from a Windows Phone app. The best approach would be to create a service layer around your database which exposes all the operations you need. This service will be called from the app. The most popular technologies for doing so on the Microsoft stack are WCF and ASP.NET Web API. Which one you choose is up to you and depends on several factors.

Possible solutions:
[Connecting Windows Phone 8 to Sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268046/connecting-windows-phone-8-to-sql-server)

[How to connect to a SQL Server database already hosted on server with windows phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19294454/how-to-connect-to-a-sql-server-database-already-hosted-on-server-with-windows-ph)

Comment: I saw those links as well, it looked like the same guy posted in quite  a few forums.  The key thing when I read that is "depends on several factors".  I will take a closer look at those options and see if I can determine their pros and cons.